# Steam logs in without being signed in

Tags: steam

Frequently now, when I start Steam it auto logs in and take me to my Library. If I look to the bottom right corner, under `VIEW FRIENDS LIST` it says `0 Online`. If I actually click this the Friends window pops up but asks me to 'sign in'.

Doing so will have all my friends appear instantly so; it's as if Steam thought I said 'start in offline mode' or something. *However* this randomly happens *during gameplay* as well (I.e. I'll be signed in on entering a game, later I look to invite someone to a game to find I've been signed out).

No notifications, nada. I can't find any settings pertaining to this and was just wondering if you could suggest anything (E.g. delete specific config and magic happens).

<sub>My google fu fails me; all the results are invariably `Disable from running at startup` and `Run steam in offline mode`</sub>

---

Addendum:
Just to try it I actually went and clicked `Go Offline...`, and when Steam restarted; the friends count was zero BUT when I clicked it the friends window didn't have a button to 'sign on', it just had a message that 'you cannot see friends in offline mode'. So I guess my condition is separate from that.

Comment: It sounds like its not a steam sign-in issue, its only the "friends" and messaging portion, which is separate from signing in to the client.  Go to settings and under the friends tab check if "Automatically Sign into Friends when I start Steam" option is checked.

Comment: It's checked. I'll try unchecking it, restarting and then reselecting it and restarting. Maybe it's not saved somewhere as being enabled

Comment: unchecking it and restarting produced the exact problem. now to wait and see if cycling it worked (because it was never an always repeatable thing). odd how i'd get signed out of `friends` during gameplay though

Comment: also the steam client just updated, so I have no idea if the issue resolves what fixed it xD

Comment: Under steam settings you can opt-in and out of steam beta test,if there is a bug with steam changing this can help you on occasion.

Comment: No it just did it again :/